# How to reverse the output of EXTRACT() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, datetime, temporal

I have the following query -

```
SELECT NOW(6) AS output1, CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()), EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW()), EXTRACT(HOUR_MICROSECOND FROM NOW(6))) AS output2;
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| output1                    | output2            |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| 2021-12-07 02:06:28.783259 | 202112720628783259 |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
```

Now I want to reverse the result - `202112720628783259` to `2021-12-07 02:06:28.783259`. But I can't think of a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `output2`, the day, hour, and minute have one digit. So you can't reliably parse that back to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

I suggest you instead use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and its reverse, [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
SELECT NOW(6) AS output1, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(6), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s%f') as output2
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| output1                    | output2              |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| 2021-12-06 20:44:31.927978 | 20211206204431927978 |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am aware of those two functions. I was going through all the temporal functions in - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp Almost all of the functions listed there has a reverse, with the exception of `EXTRACT()`. So I was curious whether there is any way of reversing `EXTRACT()` as well

Comment: No, because when some datetime components have one digit, the result is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for your reply